# Return top viewed items by country using data from Google Analytics

Tags: google-app-engine, search, go, google-analytics, ranking

So I have an app written in Go on App Engine where I have items in Datastore and provide search through the Search API. **Users can view the items** and doing so feeds **view events with country information to Google Analytics**.

**I would like to understand how to use that information to e.g. return *Top Viewed Items by Country*?**

I have researched this topic quite a bit, but have not found a good approach yet. [There is a *rank* in Search](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/search/reference#DocumentMetadata), but that value will be different for each country so I cannot use that.

I can see that having different indexes (one per country) and using that rank field or a rank field per country would provide what I want. What if the items are hundreds of thousands or more? What if I would like to offer trending that might need to be updated often across the whole dataset and not just a counter? Is this the best approach?

Maybe this is a limitation of what I currently can do on App Engine?

How would one approach this generally and maybe with another Search like Elastic Search?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's interesting to see how some people just down-vote or vote close without any improvement suggestions... how can I improve the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this report:

Google Analytics > Reporting > Behavior > Site Content > All Pages

Comment: Thanks @Alex, but I have the data through the API, but I would like to integrate it with Search API to that it ranks the results according to event data from GA.

Comment: @murrekatt you can get such report via API. Use Core Reporting API https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/ . Metrics is ga:pageviews , dimension is ga:PagePath , sort descending -ga:pageviews . Try query explorer https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/ with such values http://prnt.sc/8rum3c

Comment: @Alex thanks again, but this is not what I ask for :-) My question is how to use that data (order) from GA when I search and get results using the Search API on App Engine. The GA information might not have all items to start with and even more it is not a search query - it's a global thing unless I sprinkle it with much more dimensions that I can query and slice it on.